# Cannot change global shortcuts on Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE: "Failed to contact the KDE global shortcuts daemon"

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, kde-plasma

I would like to change the ALT-CTRL-L shortcut in Ubuntu 20.04. Custom shortcuts module or Standard shortcuts module is working. But I'm trying to open Global shortcuts module on Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE, but after open Settings => Global shortcuts window will freeze and after short time will display the following message: "Failed to contact the KDE global shortcuts daemon".

[image]

kgglobalaccel5 is running

[image]

Thanks a lot for each answer.

Comment: I think this can be better addressed at https://askubuntu.com/